# TeX Mode : making backward-word behaviour take into account Backslashes (\)

Tags: latex, syntax-table

In TeX Mode, backward-word (`M-b`) stops when it encounters a backslash character (`\`).

For example, when the cursor point is after a `\begin` and I type `M-b`, the cursor point ends up between the `\` (backslash character) and the `b` character, while I would like to have it before the backslash.

So to obtain this behaviour I tried the following, but it does not seems to be working. Any idea why?

```
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook #'(lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?\ "w")))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the answer, it was just me forgetting that **\** is an escape character. The following works fine:

```
(add-hook 'tex-mode-hook #'(lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?\\ "w")))
```